# Reverse query by dependency in NuGet API

Tags: c#, nuget

Following the tip in [this blog post by Phil Haack](https://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/23/how-to-find-out-which-nuget-packages-depend-on-yours.aspx/) I can make queries against the NuGet API searching for packages which contain a dependency to a given other package. Here an example searching for packages referencing `EntityFramework` and selecting the properties `Id` and `Dependencies` (I left the URL encoding so that you can paste this in the browser directly):

```
https://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc/Packages?$filter=substringof(%27EntityFramework%27,%20Dependencies)%20eq%20true&$select=Id,Dependencies
```

This works but only gives you a certain amount of package informations (max 100) for one request in XML (if any was found) and a query url for the next possible result set at the end. So I could recall the API over and over again this way.

Does anyone know how to achieve the same thing using the NuGet C# API ([reference here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/nuget-api-v3)):

```
var searchTerm = "I NEED THIS STRING";
var skip = 0;
var take = 100;
var packageSource = new PackageSource("https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json");
var providers = new List<Lazy<INuGetResourceProvider>>();
providers.AddRange(Repository.Provider.GetCoreV3());
var sourceRepository = new SourceRepository(packageSource, providers);
var searchResource = await sourceRepository.GetResourceAsync<PackageSearchResource>();
var results = await searchResource.SearchAsync(searchTerm, new SearchFilter(false), skip, take, logger, CancellationToken.None);
```